# Bendy Bones Mouth Driver's Setup

Tags: rigging, bones

I am trying to drive the (in y) of the selected bone with the (z scale) of the (ctr_mouth_r)

[image]

But it doesn't work it twists in a weird way

[image]

Actually, I was trying to follow this tutorial [Bendy Bones Mouth Setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zmWmJLfspg)

Here is my blend file  :

[image]

Much appreciated!